# Uniqueness of Solutions of a First Order ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm aware of the Existence and Uniqueness theorem for Differential Equations, however, as far as I know, the theorem pertains to specific functions as solutions and not a family of curves. I was wondering if a proof exists for the following statement, crudely stated:

> If $y'=f(x,y)$, where $x$ and $y$ are real variables, the solution for this equation is satisfied by only one family of curves.

Please provide an explanation with your answer.

Comment: "The solutions of $y' = f(x, y)$" *defines* a family of curves. And quite obviously, any other family of curves must have a least one curve that isn't a solution, or else it wouldn't be a different family of curves. You are going to have to refine the notion a bit before it is something useful.

Comment: @PaulSinclair : Right, of course, thank you very much.